# Build errors while trying to add boost::stacktrace to CMake project

Tags: c++, linux, boost, cmake

I'm trying to add `boost::stacktrace` library to my project via CMake. CMake finds all required libs well, but when I call `boost::stacktrace::stacktrace()` to print stack information into `std::cout` - it gives me the following error:

```
undefined reference to 'dladdr'
```

I've already tried to add the `-ldl` compile flag to the `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` compile flags to see if it can help, but it doesn't work. I understand that I missed some required packages, but I don't know which. Maybe you could advise me.

- Gcc version 7.4.0 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04)
- Boost version 1.68.0

Here is some code:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# cmake version & project name

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(stack_trace_exmpl)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# project flags config

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD      17)
set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD        11)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG   "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -g3 -pthread")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG     "-g3")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS         "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -pthread -ldl")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS           "-Wall")

set(BOOST_ROOT              "/opt/Boost_1_68_0/")

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# find Boost libs

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME OFF)

find_package(
    Boost 1.68.0
    COMPONENTS REQUIRED
        stacktrace_basic
        stacktrace_backtrace
        stacktrace_addr2line
        stacktrace_noop
)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# project sources & project's type

file(GLOB SRCS "*.cpp")
file(GLOB HDRS "*.hpp")

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${HDRS} ${SRCS})

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# link libraries

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_BASIC_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_BACKTRACE_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_ADDR2LINE_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_NOOP_LIBRARY}
)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
# include directories

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------#
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>

void tracesToCout( int _n )
{
    std::cout << boost::stacktrace::stacktrace();

    if( _n > 0 )
    {
        tracesToCout( --_n );
    }
}

int main()
{
    tracesToCout( 5 );

    return 0;
}
```

**CMake output:**

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Boost: /opt/Boost_1_68_0/include (found suitable version "1.68.0", minimum required is "1.68.0") found components:  stacktrace_basic stacktrace_backtrace stacktrace_addr2line stacktrace_noop 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/user/Work/boost_stacktrace/Debug64
```

**build output:**

```
CMakeFiles/stack_trace_exmpl.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::stacktrace::detail::location_from_symbol::location_from_symbol(void const*)':
main.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost10stacktrace6detail20location_from_symbolC2EPKv[_ZN5boost10stacktrace6detail20location_from_symbolC5EPKv]+0x4e): undefined reference to `dladdr'
CMakeFiles/stack_trace_exmpl.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `boost::stacktrace::frame::name[abi:cxx11]() const':
main.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost10stacktrace5frame4nameB5cxx11Ev[_ZNK5boost10stacktrace5frame4nameB5cxx11Ev]+0x31): undefined reference to `dladdr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/stack_trace_exmpl.dir/build.make:87: recipe for target 'stack_trace_exmpl' failed
make[2]: *** [stack_trace_exmpl] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/stack_trace_exmpl.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/stack_trace_exmpl.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You might try linking the `dl` library at the *end* of your `target_link_libraries()` call instead: `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC ... dl)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Turning my comment into an answer:*

Because the `dl` library is needed by `boost::stacktrace` (see the Boost [requirements](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/stacktrace/configuration_and_build.html)), the `dl` library should be linked *after* the Boost `stacktrace` libraries are linked. To ensure this ordering, link the `dl` library (and perhaps `pthread` as well) at the end of the [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) call instead:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_BASIC_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_BACKTRACE_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_ADDR2LINE_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC ${Boost_STACKTRACE_NOOP_LIBRARY}
    PUBLIC pthread dl
)
```

Comment: **why** perhaps pthread as well?

Comment: @kevr The OP was using the `-pthread` flag also in the example, so this may also need to be moved after the Boost stacktrace library linkages.

Comment: You can use the ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS} variable too.